# Android Kotlin sorting by collator

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I want to sort a list of objects based on one field(player.name), but in Spanish there are accents that don't have to be taken into account when ordering.

I sort the list:

```
strikers.sortedWith(compareBy { it.name })
```

But I have no idea how to apply to the above sorting

```
val spanishCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale("es", "ES"))
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
val spanishCollator = strikers.sortedWith(Comparator { s1, s2 ->
                Collator.getInstance(Locale("es", "ES")).compare(s1,s2)
            })
```

Comment: I've modified it a little bit, but that is what I wanted.

    strikers.sortedWith(Comparator { player1, player2 ->
            Collator.getInstance(Locale("es", "ES")).compare(player1.name, player2.name)
        })

Comment: I'm glad that it helps you ^^

Comment: You're creating a new instance of Locale for every two strings compared, seems not a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 14):

`Collator` class implements `Comparator` interface, so you can use it to compare names as following:

```
strikers.sortedWith(compareBy(spanishCollator) { it.name })
```

Here we use it as a comparator argument of [`compareBy`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) function overload, that takes both the value selector `{ it.name }` and the comparator `spanishCollator` that compares these values.